# In the 'first questions' queue you can choose the 'Edit' action even when the post already has a pending edit

Tags: bug, status-review, review-queues, edits, first-questions

I came across a question in the 'first questions' queue and wanted to help improve its formatting and grammar.

[image]

After I finished editing and clicked on 'Save edits', the following message appeared.

[image]

Is this meant to happen? I just spent 5-10 mins of my time for this.

The **First posts queue** used to be like this:

[image]

In contrast this is how the **First Questions queue**  is:

[image]

Comment: So you think this is more likely a bug and not just two users editing the post at the same time? Then that other users submits their edit first, then you can't save yours.

Comment: @Tom Don't think so, test it yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29671891. The edit queue is full but you can still enter edit page.

Comment: this looks more than the developers has to work on its ideas

Comment: @HardcoreGamer You're right, this really looks like bug. Btw the queue isn't full, but there is a pending edit suggestion waiting to be reviewed. But I agree that allowing the reviewer to select "edit" there is incorrect.

Comment: Editing in the queue works as expected for me (I have full edit privilege, so the problem might only be for suggestions) . There was no prior edit waiting for approval. Afaik, the queue also wasn't full. Note, that for this specific question, editing probably wasn't the necessary thing to do since it is off-topic.

Comment: @BDL "There was no prior edit waiting for approval." ... there was and you rolled over it with your 2k editing rights: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29672121

Comment: @Wait, what? I wasn't able to see the pending edit from inside the queue. Usually, even with full edit privilege, you can't simply override another suggested edit. Probably counts as an additional bug with the new review queues.

Comment: @BDL Yes, that's the bug. You currently need to go to the actual post to check if there is a pending edit. I agree, that this is an issue in that queue.

Comment: @BDL You *could* override the edit if you started editing before the suggestion was made and finish editing after the suggestion. I suppose that's sort of what happens in the queue - bypasses the existing suggestion. It *shouldn't*, of course, so it seems like a bug.

Comment: @Tom: Yup, stupid me. [I reported it in the meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369092/273575)

Comment: Thanks all for reproducing this issue and reported it to meta.SE